# MERN stack error on production with mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I try to deploy a MERN stack on ubuntu Nginx but i have the following error:

```
0|app      | Assertion failed: You must provide either mongoUrl|clientPromise|client in options
0|app      | Error: Cannot init client. Please provide correct options
0|app      |     at new MongoStore (/root/sites/vadasz-backend/node_modules/connect-mongo/build/main/lib/MongoStore.js:119:19)
```

I have checked the credentials for mango db
everything works on my local machine but as soon as i try to deploy on a VPS it suddenly stop working.

This is my mongo settings:

```
const dotenv = require("dotenv");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const MongoStore = require("connect-mongo");

dotenv.config();

mongoose.set("strictQuery", true);
mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO_URL, {
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  useUnifiedTopology: true,
});

const connection = mongoose.connection;

try {
  connection.once("open", () => {
    console.log("database connected successfully...");
  });
} catch (error) {
  console.log("connection failed...");
}

let store = new MongoStore({
  mongoUrl: process.env.MONGO_URL,
  collection: "sessions",
});

app.use(
  session({
    secret: process.env.SESS_SECREET,
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    store: store,
    cookie: {
      secure: "auto",
    },
  })
);
```

Is there any advise ?

Comment: If you use `dotenv.config({debug:true});`, are there any surprises?

Comment: I get this: [dotenv@16.0.3][DEBUG] Failed to load /root/.env ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/root/.env'

Comment: Seems your `.env` file needs to be at `/root/.env` or you need to [tell `dotenv` where it is](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv#user-content-path).

Comment: Thanks, it solved. I added this line: dotenv.config({debug: true, path: __dirname + '/.env'});

Comment: Write a good answer and I'll upvote it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing this line

```
dotenv.config();
```

to this line

```
dotenv.config({debug: true, path: __dirname + '/.env'});
```

solved the problem.